# Issue with the wifi in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, wifi, wifimanager

I am working on a educational related apps. My app functionality is working well  when the WIFI is connected otherwise it is getting crashed.

1. In my app I am connecting with the server using NSURLRequest class its working.
2. the download also not having any problem if the wifi is available.
   problem rectification: I have to know weather the my app device is connected with external network or not.

So, how can I know my app is connected with the wifi or not?

Comment: Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What are you trying to accomplish? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting? (no, it's not self-evident, that's why I'm asking)

Comment: Rather than treat the symptom, I'd look to the cause.  Why is your application crashing when it's not connected to WiFi?  I'd fix that first.

Comment: i am unable figure out the cause..but it happens only when the wifi is not available..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following link consists source code, in which it consists how to check the reachability. That means the wifi or any network is connected of not.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: thank you satya.i need weather the wifi is available to the device or not..so for that can call any methods.

Comment: once check the source code and study the reachability class, in that you will get so many features.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides sample code called "Reachability" to detect when the network is available. That would be a good starting point, though a quick Google should locate some alternatives.